# Creating time series in R

Tags: r, csv, time-series

I have a CSV file containing data as follows-

> date, group, integer_value

The date starts from 01-January-2013 to 31-October-2015 for the 20 groups contained in the data.

I want to create a time series for the 20 different groups. But the dates are not continuous and have sporadic gaps in it, hence-

```
group4series <- ts(group4, frequency = 365.25, start = c(2013,1,1))
```

works from programming point of view but is not correct due to gaps in data.

How can I use the 'date' column of the data to create the time series instead of the usual 'frequency' parameter of 'ts()' function?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a representative sample of your data with `dput`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `zoo::zoo` instead of `ts`.

Since you don't provide sample data, let's generate daily data, and remove some days to introduce "gaps".

```
set.seed(2018)
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015/12/01"), as.Date("2016/07/01"), by = "1 day")
dates <- dates[sample(length(dates), 100)]
```

We construct a sample `data.frame`

```
df <- data.frame(
    dates = dates,
    val = cumsum(runif(length(dates))))
```

To turn `df` into a `zoo` timeseries, you can do the following

```
library(zoo)
ts <- with(df, zoo(val, dates))
```

Let's plot the timeseries

```
plot.zoo(ts)
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the `with` statement could be written as: `ts <- read.zoo(df)`